The data I'm trying to tidy has all the characterstics and characterstic categories in one column, I don't know how to seperate them
I've been doing this for hours and I can't figure it out.
I am using the following data sets from the U.S. Census Bureau Household Pulse Survey. I chose the latest data that they had for each year:
2022 - https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/demo/tables/hhp/2022/wk51/food1_week51.xlsx
2021 - https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/demo/tables/hhp/2021/wk40/food1_week40.xlsx
2020 - https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/demo/tables/hhp/2020/wk20/food1_week20.xlsx
I started by combining all three files together to get one big dataframe that looks at all three years. Along with that, I combined all the sheets into one data frame because I want to look at all the different regions. I added columns that would tell me from which region and year each row of data comes from.
I used the following code:
# Listing file names
file_names <- c("food_sufficiency_2020.xlsx", "food_sufficiency_2021.xlsx", "food_sufficiency_2022.xlsx")

# Function to read and clean each sheet
read_and_clean_sheet <- function(file) {

# Extracting the year from the file name
year <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", file))

# Reading all sheets from the Excel file
sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(file)

# Reading each sheet and cleaning it
dfs <- lapply(sheets, function(sheet) {

# Reading the sheet
df <- readxl::read_excel(file, sheet = sheet)

# Removing the first few rows that explain the sheet's purpose
df <- df[-(1:5), ]

# Renaming the first column to "Select Characteristics"
names(df)[1] <- "Select Characteristics"

names(df)[2] <- "Total"

names(df)[3] <- "Enough of the kinds of food wanted"

names(df)[4] <- "Enough food, but not always the kinds wanted"

names(df)[5] <- "Sometimes not enough to eat"

names(df)[6] <- "Often not enough to eat"

names(df)[7] <- "Did not report"

# Adding a new column for the sheet name
df$Region <- sheet

# Adding a new column for the year
df$Year <- year

# Returning the cleaned data frame
return(df)

})

# Combining all cleaned sheets into one dataframe
combined_df <- bind_rows(dfs)

# Returning the combined dataframe
return(combined_df)

}

# Reading and cleaning all sheets from all Excel files
all_data <- lapply(file_names, read_and_clean_sheet)

# Combining all dataframes into one big dataframe
final_df <- bind_rows(all_data)

view(final_df)

If you run the code, you will see that the "Select Characteristics" column has all the characterstic category names and the corresponding characteristics all together.
I want to seperate all that into two different columns. One that would be called "Characteristic Category" and the other one "Select Characteristics". So, for example, in the "Characteristic Category" it would say "Age". In the same row but in the column labeled "Select Characteristics" it would say "18-24". That way, I can work with the data more easily. You would be able to see what group each row came from.
Here is the output that I got from running the code: the somewhat tidied data
Here is the original data in case you can't open the links I posted: snippit of og data in excel - as you can see, the categories are bolded, and the corresponding characteristics are below it. I want the category and corresponding characteristic to be in seperate columns.
Here is an example that I made of what I would like the final product to look like (in turns of the two columns): example data frame

"week_20" has different variables from the others: is that ok?

I figured it out! Here's my code:
Here I am combining all excel files and sheets together.
# listing file names
file_names <- c("food_sufficiency_2020.xlsx", "food_sufficiency_2021.xlsx", "food_sufficiency_2022.xlsx")

# creating a function to read and clean each sheet
read_and_clean_sheet <- function(file) {
  # extracting the year from the file name
  year <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", file))
  
  # reading all sheets from the Excel file
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(file)
  
  # reading each sheet and cleaning it
  dfs <- lapply(sheets, function(sheet) {
    # Read the sheet
    df <- readxl::read_excel(file, sheet = sheet)
    
    # removing the first few rows that explain the sheet's purpose
    df <- df[-(1:5), ]
    
    # renaming the first column to "select characteristics"
    names(df)[1] <- "Select Characteristics"
    names(df)[2] <- "Total"
    names(df)[3] <- "Enough of the kinds of food wanted"
    names(df)[4] <- "Enough food, but not always the kinds wanted"
    names(df)[5] <- "Sometimes not enough to eat"
    names(df)[6] <- "Often not enough to eat"
    names(df)[7] <- "Did not report"
    
    # adding a new column for the sheet name
    df$Region <- sheet
    
    # adding a new column for the year
    df$Year <- year
    
    # returning the cleaned data frame
    return(df)
})
  
  # combining all cleaned sheets into one data frame
  combined_df <- bind_rows(dfs)
  
  # returning the combined data frame
  return(combined_df)
}

# reading and cleaning all sheets from all excel files
all_data <- lapply(file_names, read_and_clean_sheet)

# combining all data frames into one big data frame
final_df <- bind_rows(all_data)


Then I tidied the data by adding and removing columns!
# adding a column for food sufficiency status 
food <- final_df |>
  pivot_longer(cols = c("Enough of the kinds of food wanted", "Enough food, but not always the kinds wanted", "Sometimes not enough to eat", "Often not enough to eat", "Did not report"), names_to = "Food Sufficiency Status", values_to = "Sample Size")

# creating a new column for 'Characteristic_Category' and filling it with the corresponding category
food<- food |>
  mutate(Characteristic_Category = ifelse(grepl("^[A-Za-z]", `Select Characteristics`), `Select Characteristics`, NA)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(Characteristic_Category)

# removing rows with NA in 'Characteristic_Category'
food <- food[complete.cases(food), ]

# changing the order of the columns
food <- food |>
  select(Region, Year, "Food Sufficiency Status", Characteristic_Category, `Select Characteristics`, "Sample Size", Total)

# renaming columns
food <- food |>
  rename("Selected Characteristic" = `Select Characteristics`,
         "Characteristic Category" = Characteristic_Category)

# converting some variables to be numeric
food <- food |>
  mutate(`Sample Size` = as.numeric(`Sample Size`),
         Total = as.numeric(Total))

# viewing food sufficiency data
view(food)


Here is this final output: 
As you can see that there is a lot more rows - I did the following:

Combined all the excel files and all the pages within those excel files into one data frame.
Created columns for the year and region so that one could tell from what year/region the row of data is from.
Took the messy column and split it into two columns - characteristic category and selected characteristic. That way, a specific selected characteristic will be in the same row as its corresponding characteristic category, making the data easier to read and understand.


The rows that contain the characteristic headings don't contain any data. We can use that fact to get the row indices of these heading rows. These indices are where each new characteristic heading begins. We can use these locations to create a new column with the correct characteristic values.
One other thing to make your life easier: Use the skip argument of read_excel to start reading the data in row 6, so that you'll only have to rename the first two columns (they're each merged across rows 5 and 6 in the Excel file, so they don't get read properly, even when using skip=5).
Here's an example using one sheet of one data file. You can then use lapply (or purrr::map) to iterate this method over sheets and files.
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

# Read and clean data 
x=read_excel("~/downloads/food1_week51.xlsx", skip=5)

## Rename first two columns and remove footnote rows
x = x %>% 
  rename("Select Characteristics"=...1, Total=...2) %>% 
  filter(!grepl("^\\*", `Select Characteristics`))

## Add "Total" characteristic
x$`Select Characteristics`[1] = "Total"

# Create new column for the characteristic headings

## Get the row indices where each characteristic heading is located.
##  These are the rows marking the beginning of each new heading.
b = which(is.na(x$Total))

## Add the headings in the correct rows but in a new column
x$characteristic = NA
x$characteristic[b] = x$`Select Characteristics`[b]

## Fill rows downward from each heading to populate the correct characteristic 
## headings in each row
x = x %>% fill(characteristic) 

## Move characteristic to first column position and remove the original 
# heading rows, which have no data
x = x %>% 
  relocate(characteristic) %>%   
  filter(!is.na(Total))

# Check that the new column has the correct heading values
x %>% select(1:4) %>% print(n=25)
#> # A tibble: 155 × 4
#>    characteristic           Select Characteristi…¹  Total Enough of the kinds …²
#>    <chr>                    <chr>                   <dbl>                  <dbl>
#>  1 Total                    Total                  2.52e8              122834767
#>  2 Age                      18 - 24                2.44e7               10671381
#>  3 Age                      25 - 39                6.50e7               30456884
#>  4 Age                      40 - 54                6.39e7               29086982
#>  5 Age                      55 - 64                4.41e7               21963272
#>  6 Age                      65 and above           5.52e7               30656247
#>  7 Sex at birth             Male                   1.23e8               62804115
#>  8 Sex at birth             Female                 1.29e8               60030652
#>  9 Gender                   Cisgender male         1.18e8               61204194
#> 10 Gender                   Cisgender female       1.24e8               58704795
#> 11 Gender                   Transgender            2.97e6                 741755
#> 12 Gender                   None of these          4.07e6                1297984
#> 13 Gender                   Did not report         3.20e6                 886038
#> 14 Sexual orientation       Gay or lesbian         7.97e6                3984033
#> 15 Sexual orientation       Straight               2.17e8              108418407
#> 16 Sexual orientation       Bisexual               1.29e7                5523515
#> 17 Sexual orientation       Something else         5.59e6                1978187
#> 18 Sexual orientation       I don’t know           5.60e6                2008934
#> 19 Sexual orientation       Did not report         3.53e6                 921692
#> 20 Lesbian, Gay, Bisexual … Yes                    2.25e7                9923953
#> 21 Lesbian, Gay, Bisexual … No                     2.13e8              107129115
#> 22 Lesbian, Gay, Bisexual … Other                  1.11e7                4207118
#> 23 Lesbian, Gay, Bisexual … Did not report         5.35e6                1574581
#> 24 Hispanic origin and Race Hispanic or Latino (m… 4.38e7               15689382
#> 25 Hispanic origin and Race White alone, not Hisp… 1.57e8               83632594
#> # ℹ 130 more rows
#> # ℹ abbreviated names: ¹​`Select Characteristics`,
#> #   ²​`Enough of the kinds of food wanted`

Created on 2024-04-17 with reprex v2.1.0

This file food1_week20.xlsx is different from food1_week40.xlsx and food1_week51.xlsx..


..so I gave them different treatment. Here's my take:
food1_week20.xlsx:
# Week 20 import ----------------------------------------------------------
week_20 <- "food1_week20.xlsx" # Use the full name

# Read all sheets
week_20 <- map_dfr(
  excel_sheets(week_20),
  \(x) read_excel(week_20, sheet = x, skip = 8, col_names = FALSE, col_types = "text") %>% 
      mutate(region = x, file = basename(week_20)))

# Rename the columns
colnames(week_20) <- c("category", "mean_amount_home", "mean_amount_elsewhere", "region", "file")

# week_20 wrangling -------------------------------------------------------
week_20 <- week_20 %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(category, "^\\*{1,2}")) %>% 
  mutate(.by = region, category_id = cumsum(if_else(is.na(mean_amount_home), 1, 0)))

week_20 <- left_join(
  week_20 %>% 
    filter(is.na(mean_amount_home)) %>% 
    distinct(region, category, category_id),
  week_20 %>% 
    rename(characteristic = category) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(mean_amount_home)),
  by = c("region", "category_id"))

week_20 <- week_20 %>% 
  mutate(across(
    starts_with("mean"), 
    \(x) if_else(str_detect(x, "\\d"), as.numeric(x), NA_real_)))

"Week 20" will look like this:
> week_20
# A tibble: 3,618 × 7
   region category                            category_id characteristic                    mean_amount_home mean_amount_elsewhere file             
   <chr>  <chr>                                     <dbl> <chr>                                        <dbl>                 <dbl> <chr>            
 1 US     Household size                                1 1 person in the household                     124.                  46.3 food1_week20.xlsx
 2 US     Household size                                1 2 people in the household                     176.                  61.9 food1_week20.xlsx
 3 US     Household size                                1 3 people in the household                     210.                  83.9 food1_week20.xlsx
 4 US     Household size                                1 4 people in the household                     241.                  89.9 food1_week20.xlsx
 5 US     Household size                                1 5 people in the household                     274.                 110.  food1_week20.xlsx
 6 US     Household size                                1 6 people in the household                     290.                 103.  food1_week20.xlsx
 7 US     Household size                                1 7 or more people in the household             343.                 117.  food1_week20.xlsx
 8 US     Number of children in the household           2 No children in the household                  186.                  70.2 food1_week20.xlsx
 9 US     Number of children in the household           2 1 child in the household                      235.                  89.5 food1_week20.xlsx
10 US     Number of children in the household           2 2 children in the household                   268.                  98.2 food1_week20.xlsx
# ℹ 3,608 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

food1_week40.xlsx and food1_week51.xlsx (other weeks, as long as they have the same format) turn:
# Other weeks import ------------------------------------------------------
other_weeks <- c("food1_week40.xlsx", "food1_week51.xlsx") # full names!

# Read all sheets from all files
other_weeks <- map_dfr(
  other_weeks,
  \(x_file) map_dfr(
    excel_sheets(x_file),
    \(x_sheet) read_excel(x_file, sheet = x_sheet, skip = 8, col_names = FALSE, col_types = "text") %>% 
        mutate(region = x_sheet, file = basename(x_file))))

# Rename the columns
colnames(other_weeks) <- c("category", "total", "enough", "not_always_enough", "sometimes_not_enough", "often_not_enough", "did_not_report", "region", "file")

# Other weeks wrangling ---------------------------------------------------

# Create IDs: the files have few different categories!
categories_id <- other_weeks %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(category, "^\\*{1,2}"), is.na(total)) %>%
  distinct(category) %>% 
  rowid_to_column("category_id")

other_weeks <- other_weeks %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(category, "^\\*{1,2}")) %>% 
  left_join(categories_id, by = "category") %>% 
  fill(category_id, .direction = "down")

other_weeks <- left_join(
  other_weeks %>% 
    filter(is.na(total)) %>% 
    distinct(category, category_id, region, file), #or just `select`
  other_weeks %>% 
    rename(characteristic = category) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(total)),
  by = c("region", "category_id", "file"))

other_weeks <- other_weeks %>% 
  mutate(across(
    total:last_col(), 
    \(x) if_else(str_detect(x, "\\d"), as.numeric(x), NA_real_)))

"Other weeks" will look like:
> other_weeks
# A tibble: 20,435 × 11
   category     category_id region file              characteristic       total   enough not_always_enough sometimes_not_enough often_not_enough did_not_report
   <chr>              <int> <chr>  <chr>             <chr>                <dbl>    <dbl>             <dbl>                <dbl>            <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 Age                    1 US     food1_week40.xlsx 18 - 24           19739527 10075128           4141845              1050828           277168        4194557
 2 Age                    1 US     food1_week40.xlsx 25 - 39           68339338 37430352          14780733              5282840          1355385        9490028
 3 Age                    1 US     food1_week40.xlsx 40 - 54           63742483 34595535          13420164              5778568          1645922        8302294
 4 Age                    1 US     food1_week40.xlsx 55 - 64           43443848 26926305           8439394              2546590           681247        4850313
 5 Age                    1 US     food1_week40.xlsx 65 and above      55000253 37990197           9247210              1519466           978678        5264702
 6 Sex at birth           2 US     food1_week40.xlsx Male             121078275 73554454          22197888              7151883          2455473       15718578
 7 Sex at birth           2 US     food1_week40.xlsx Female           129187174 73463064          27831457              9026409          2482928       16383316
 8 Gender                 3 US     food1_week40.xlsx Cisgender male   116079269 71954617          21103910              6745956          2112984       14161803
 9 Gender                 3 US     food1_week40.xlsx Cisgender female 124141286 72007276          26828032              8534054          2239809       14532116
10 Gender                 3 US     food1_week40.xlsx Transgender        2935988   924781            679919               310984           199773         820532
# ℹ 20,425 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

Finishing, even they aren't same-same, you can merge them together:
# Build the "all data" ----------------------------------------------------
all_data <- bind_rows(
  pivot_longer(week_20, starts_with("mean")),
  pivot_longer(other_weeks, total:last_col()))

all_data <- select(all_data, file, region, category, characteristic, name, value)

Final output:
> all_data
# A tibble: 129,846 × 6
   file              region category       characteristic            name                  value
   <chr>             <chr>  <chr>          <chr>                     <chr>                 <dbl>
 1 food1_week20.xlsx US     Household size 1 person in the household mean_amount_home      124. 
 2 food1_week20.xlsx US     Household size 1 person in the household mean_amount_elsewhere  46.3
 3 food1_week20.xlsx US     Household size 2 people in the household mean_amount_home      176. 
 4 food1_week20.xlsx US     Household size 2 people in the household mean_amount_elsewhere  61.9
 5 food1_week20.xlsx US     Household size 3 people in the household mean_amount_home      210. 
 6 food1_week20.xlsx US     Household size 3 people in the household mean_amount_elsewhere  83.9
 7 food1_week20.xlsx US     Household size 4 people in the household mean_amount_home      241. 
 8 food1_week20.xlsx US     Household size 4 people in the household mean_amount_elsewhere  89.9
 9 food1_week20.xlsx US     Household size 5 people in the household mean_amount_home      274. 
10 food1_week20.xlsx US     Household size 5 people in the household mean_amount_elsewhere 110. 
# ℹ 129,836 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

Hope it helps!
